# Achive dynamic string interpolation in Scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, string-interpolation

I have a string with the functions that need to go into `.agg` functions of my intended dataframe.
MY data dataframe looks like

```
val client = Seq((1,"A","D",10),(2,"A","D",5),(3,"B","C",56),(5,"B","D",67)).toDF("ID","Categ","subCat","Amnt")
+---+-----+------+----+
| ID|Categ|subCat|Amnt|
+---+-----+------+----+
|  1|    A|     D|  10|
|  2|    A|     D|   5|
|  3|    B|     C|  56|
|  5|    B|     D|  67|
+---+-----+------+----+
```

so I'm tryin to interpolate this sting

```
val str= "s"$count(ID) as Total,$sum(Amnt) as amt""
```

I want to achieve this as output

```
client.groupBy("Categ","subCat").agg(sum("Amnt") as "amt",count("ID") as "Total").show()
+-----+------+---+-----+
|Categ|subCat|amt|Total|
+-----+------+---+-----+
|    B|     C| 56|    1|
|    A|     D| 15|    2|
|    B|     D| 67|    1|
+-----+------+---+-----+
```

**I tried this**

```
 client.groupBy("Categ","subCat").agg(s"$str").show()
```

**getting an error**

```
> error: overloaded method value agg with alternatives:
```

> (expr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exprs:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame 
>   (exprs: java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>      (exprs:
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>      (aggExpr: (String, String),aggExprs: (String,
>   String)*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  cannot be applied to (String)

I also Tried expr

```
    val str="sum(Amnt) as amt"
    client.groupBy("Categ","subCat").agg(expr(str)).show()
```

> ```
>  this return the desired outcome
> ```

```
    +-----+------+---+
    |Categ|subCat|amt|
    +-----+------+---+
    |    B|     C| 56|
    |    A|     D| 15|
    |    B|     D| 67|
    +-----+------+---+
```

but again when i try 
**`val str="sum(Amnt) as amt,count(ID) as ID_tot"`**

```
    client.groupBy("Categ","subCat").agg(expr(str)).show()
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input ',' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 16)
```

Comment: you are trying to mix Spark SQL and Dataframe APIs here. This is not possible. If the requirements demand strictly string interpolation as you mentioned then you must go for pure Spark SQL solution i.e `select count(ID) as Total, sum(Amnt) as amt from client group by Categ ,subCat`

Comment: @ Alexandros I was thinking that as my backup plan.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.scala) `agg` has 3 overloads 1.  `agg(aggExpr: (String, String), aggExprs: (String, String)*): DataFrame` 2.  `agg(exprs: Map[String, String]): DataFrame` 3. `agg(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): DataFrame` none of them accepts a string. So you can either do something like `df.groupBy("Categ","subCat").agg("Amnt" -> "sum", "ID" -> "count")` or `df.groupBy("Categ","subCat").agg(Map("Amnt" -> "sum", "ID" -> "count"))` or SQL as shown above

Answer (score 3):

You can use different API to achieve what you want

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
client
  .groupBy("Categ", "subCat")
  .agg(
    sum("Amnt").as("Amnt"), 
    count(lit("1")).as("Total"))
  .show()
```

Alternatively, go full SparkSQL but I would discourage this pattern if you are trying to inject user's input.

```
spark.sql(s"select Categ, subCat, $str from client group by Categ, subCat")
```

Comment: That aggregation function is part of the string itself 

val str= "s"$count(ID) as Total,$sum(Amnt) as amt""

Comment: @KalpishSinghal alright, haven't noticed what you were trying to do here. I have edited my answer

Comment: You are right by doing this i'll achive what i want for this job but i want this as a configurable string 
so instead of " sum("Amt") ,Count("ID") "

I can pass a string 2 in this function saying " Avg("Amnt").as("avg_amt") "

Thats where i'm looking for interpolation

Answer (score 3):

A bit crude solution: split by `,` and call `expr` on each:

```
val str="sum(Amnt) as amt,count(ID) as ID_tot"
val (first, rest) = str.split(",").map(expr).splitAt(1)
client.groupBy("Categ","subCat").agg(first, rest: _*)
```

If `,` can be a part of an expression (e.g. inside a string literal), it gets worse: try to parse it with `expr`, catch `ParseException` and see where it ends? There should really be a more straightforward way, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same by using List of String as expression -

`val str=List("sum(Amnt) as amt,count(ID) as ID_tot")`
`ds.selectExpr(str:_*)`